# How to Convert DataReader Result to Entity? ->use Emit

Tags: c#, il

Now I want   to  Convert a DataReader to an Entity . I have a method like this:

```
 private static void ReadInt32(ILGenerator il, LocalBuilder item,
                List<DbColumnInfo> columnInfoes, LocalBuilder[] colIndices, int i)
            {
               il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_S, item);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_S, colIndices[i]);

                il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, DataRecord_GetInt32);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, columnInfoes[i].SetMethod);

}
```

and call the method like here,

```
 if (IsCompatibleType(columnInfoes[i].Type, typeof(int)))
                    {
                        // item.%Property% = arg.GetInt32(%index%);
                        ReadInt32(il, item, columnInfoes, colIndices, i);
                    }
```

unfortunately, there will come up an Exception if the Data Filed in DB is NULL. As int type can't be NULL value but I made it transfer to int?. then turns out that my calling method works well.

**but here I want an extension that is while Data Filed in DB is NULL, we can use Custom attribute to indicate a default value. So I re-defined ReadInt32 as following, But to my surprise, there always comming up JIT inner Exception. I'm not familiar with IL, I really looking forward some help for you all, really appreciate.**

change the code's as following,but still exist error,the exception type is : 
System.EntryPointNotFoundException:

```
 var local = il.DeclareLocal(columnInfoes[i].Type);//int i
            Label intNull = il.DefineLabel();//int intNull;
            Label intCommon = il.DefineLabel();


            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, local);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_S, colIndices[i]);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, DataRecord_IsDBNull);// int i=isdbnull?
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, intNull);// int i=isdbnull?intNull

            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_S, colIndices[i]);//int i=isdbnull?1000:getInt(32)

            il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, DataRecord_GetInt32);//int i=isdbnull?1000:getInt32(i);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, intCommon);

            il.MarkLabel(intNull);;
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 123);//intNull=DefaultValue  columnInfoes[i].DefaultValue
            il.MarkLabel(intCommon);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_S, item);
            //il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_S, item);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, local);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, columnInfoes[i].SetMethod);
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to duplicate what dapper-dot-net is doing.

Comment: i just want to Convert a DataReader result to an Entity,when db result is NULL,it will use custom attribute.DefaultValue

Answer (score 0):

Just use [**Dapper**](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net). If it's good for SO, it will be good for you, too ;-)

Comment: i cannot open the :http://open.dapper.net/ ,error message:The service is not available. Please try again later.